# I cannot unset a cookie

Tags: php, cookies

As the title says, I'm attempting to unset a cookie.

```
   <?php     
    
          setcookie("Username", "",time() -10000000000);
          
          echo $_COOKIE["Username"]; //this still echoes out the cookie
    ?>
```

But it just ignores the "setcookie()" function.

Comment: Is the cookie still stored after a reload? I think the `setcookie()` function just creates a header for the client, but it doesn’t remove the `$_COOKIE` index. You can use the `unset()` if you need to have it removed in the code.

Answer (score -1):

Its quiet simple just set cookie value as false

```
setcookie('cookie_name', false);
```